# Where to find/purchase an offline (downloadable) Arabic corpus

Tags: corpora, arabic

I'm developing an application to teach Quran. I need some textual/lingual analysis based on a common and general corpus.

I know about King Abdulaziz City for Science and Technology (KACST) Arabic corpus, yet I can't find a place to download it. The [original website](http://www.kacstac.org.sa/) seems to be down.

Can anyone guide me to a general purpose Arabic Corpus that can be downloaded (free or paid)?

Answer (score 3):

The most convienient way to search for corpora is the [Virtual language Observatory (VLO)](https://vlo.clarin.eu), a service by the European CLARIN project. Enter "Arabic corpus" in the search slit and you'll get (at the moment of this answer writing) 1863 hits, among them the following:

- Al-Hayat corpus: http://catalog.elra.info/product_info.php?products_id=632
- Prague Arabic Dependency Treebank http://ufal.mff.cuni.cz/padt/PADT_1.0/docs/index.html
- Arabic Learner Corpus https://catalog.ldc.upenn.edu/LDC2015S10

Answer (score 1):

corpus.kacst.edu.sa

Other useful corpus links can be found here:
https://sites.google.com/a/aucegypt.edu/infoguistics/directory/Corpus-Linguistics/arabic-corpora